# Firefox extension: How to display a long description in about:addons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How can I add a long description to my Firefox extension?

There is a tag `<em:description>` in the `install.rdf` file. But, [the documentation on MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#description) says that the contents of that tag should be short:

> **description**
>   A short description of the add-on - intended for display in the user
>   interface. This description should fit on one short line of text.

I need to add information so that it is shown in the window when I press the Show More Information add-on context menu item in the Add-on Manager. How can I make a longer description be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `about:addons` each add-on has a "More" link. The information on the page displayed when you click on that link is taken from the description the developer writes on the [Mozilla Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) site once the [`.xpi` package has been uploaded to them](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/submit/1). The first image from the Mozilla Add-on site is also displayed.

The "More" page is currently populated from the following (if a lower number does not exist, then the next higher one is used):

1. The description for the Add-on from the Mozilla Add-on site
2. The [`<em:description>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#description) for the Add-on in the add-on's [`instal.rdf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests)

This is merely the behavior I have observed. I have not checked the source code to verify this is really the case. The description from the Mozilla Add-on site is used even if the add-on is currently running from a different version located on your system. In other words, if the [`<em:id>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#id) matches one on the Mozilla Add-on site, the description on the site will be used.

Upon displaying the "More" page, some requests for the information displayed are sent to/received from `https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addon_icons`.  However, I did not see a network request for the "More" page text at that time.